# EC2 after reboot: how to resolve host ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I rebooted my Ubuntu EC2 and I now can't do anything. I get the following error on trying pretty much anything:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

where the xxx is the private IP address.

**How do I resolve this error?**

As an example, it happens for this command:

```
sudo rm some_file
```

That's just an example. Pretty much nothing works.

I looked at similar questions on Stackoverflow and tried all the suggestions I found, including:

- verified in the EC2 dashboard that both the private and public IP address have not changed.
- I can access the server both with Ftp and SSH.
- The EC2's VPC has both DNS hostnames and DNS resolution enabled.
- I checked the contents of hostname with:

  cat /etc/hostname

It contains the same ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx as in the error message.

What else can I try?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441873/aws-error-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-ip-10-0-xx-xx

Comment: Yes, those are the solutions I tried... I figured it out. Turned out to be a space issue. My filesystem was full. I deleted some files and rebooted. I'll probably add that solution to the other question and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my filesystem was full. I deleted some files and revooted. Then it worked. phew